# Basic question about principle of deformation of path in complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The problem is calculating $$ \oint_C(z-z_0)^m dz ,  m=0,\pm1,\pm2,...$$ Where C is any simple closed path enclosed z0, counterclockwise.

So I know that solving by using K which is the circle $$ |z-z_0|=ρ ,counterclockwise$$
when m is non-negative integer, since $$ |z-z_0|=ρ$$ is entire function and by the Cauchy integral Thm, $$ \oint_K(z-z_0)^m dz=0$$

but I don't know how to solve this when m is negative integer.

The answer is
$$\begin{cases}
2\pi i \: (m = −1) \\
0 \: (m \ne −1)
\end{cases} $$

Comment: If follows from a straightforward application of Residue Theorem

Comment: You get from **definition** of contour integral.

Comment: Let $z=z_0+\rho e^{i \phi}$, $\phi \in [0,2 \pi]$.